# Why do I get a "There are NO KNOWN RESOURCES here" message when calling for scavengers from this location?

Tags: state-of-decay

I made a radio assistance call for survivors from [this area (an orchard; map location)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j78FF.jpg) as there is still a food resource crate there that I am unable to collect.

However, I get a "*There are NO KNOWN RESOURCES here*" message when I try to do so:
[image: screenshot]

**Why do I get this message?** I'm pretty sure there's a food resource crate as I made the radio assistance call by selecting the crate and choosing the radio assistance menu. Also, **is there a workaround here that I can do to still get scavengers to collect the resources?**

I'm playing the Steam Early Access version on the PC.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I daresay this has been fixed. I played a lot of vanilla State of Decay (and later expansions) once it was released (120h+) and never encountered this bug

Comment: Since .SE bumped this, did you happen to fix this issue?

Comment: @Oak Nope. Also, I haven't played State of Decay in a long time.

Comment: One more thing (if you remember), did you open the crate before trying to call scavengers?

Comment: @Oak I believe I haven't opened the crate (not too sure about this though as my memory on this is foggy).

Comment: @galacticninja Understandeable, after all 3 years have passed. But from all I know, if you take anything from it it's considered "empty" for the purpose of calling a scavenger (if you manage to call him he'll check it anyway), it's possible you had opened and taken something out of it. Although it's fixeable by going away from the zone

Answer (score 2):

To call for scavengers you must first search the container and verify it has a bag of resources. If the only resources left at a scavenging location are unsearched containers then you are unable to call for scavengers.

As the message says "There are no **known** resources here"

If you have searched the containers and there are still bags of resources to be collected and you still encounter this error then you've encountered a bug. Try loading them into your vehicle instead

Answer (score -1):

I've not encounter the bug, so I can't advise you on this matter, sorry. However, if the resource is too far from your home base, it's generally not worth it to call survivors to come pick it up. It takes a lot of time (since they always go on foot) and they might go missing or get surrounded on the way which means more work for you. If you can loot the stuff yourself then do so, if you can't and you don't want to lose it, dump the Rucksack you're carrying at the nearest Outpost, then head back to loot it.